# jQuery.parseJSON fails to parse valid json

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
load    : function() {
    var mastery = $('div.mastery.trees');
    this.object = $.parseJSON($('a.json.data', mastery).text());
    console.log(this.object);
}
```

this fails silently (unless i add a try/catch block around parseJSON) regardless of the content of the json data (the data i want to use - see below - or even just some very simple test data)

actual data

```
{"points":{"allowed":30,"current":0,"offense":0,"defense":0,"utility":0},"current":{"offense":{},"defense":{},"utility":{}},"trees":{"offense":{"Deadliness":{"max":3,"req":""},"Cripple":{"max":1,"req":""},"Plentiful_Bounty":{"max":1,"req":""},"Archmages_Savvy":{"max":3,"req":""},"Sorcery":{"max":4,"req":{"offense":4}},"Alacrity":{"max":4,"req":{"offense":4}},"Burning_Embers":{"max":1,"req":{"offense":8}},"Archaic_Knowledge":{"max":1,"req":{"offense":8,"Sorcery":4}},"Sunder":{"max":3,"req":{"offense":8}},"Offensive_Mastery":{"max":2,"req":{"offense":8}},"Brute_Force":{"max":3,"req":{"offense":12}},"Lethality":{"max":3,"req":{"offense":16}},"Improved_Rally":{"max":1,"req":{"offense":16}},"Havoc":{"max":1,"req":{"offense":20}}},"defense":{"Menders_Faith":{"max":1,"req":""},"Resistance":{"max":3,"req":""},"Preservation":{"max":1,"req":""},"Hardiness":{"max":3,"req":""},"Strength_of_Spirit":{"max":3,"req":{"defense":4,"Resistance":3}},"Evasion":{"max":4,"req":{"defense":4}},"Defensive_Mastery":{"max":2,"req":{"defense":8}},"Nimbleness":{"max":1,"req":{"defense":8,"Evasion":4}},"Harden_Skin":{"max":3,"req":{"defense":8,"Hardiness":3}},"Veterans_Scars":{"max":4,"req":{"defense":12}},"Willpower":{"max":1,"req":{"defense":12}},"Ardor":{"max":3,"req":{"defense":16}},"Reinforce":{"max":1,"req":{"defense":16}},"Tenacity":{"max":1,"req":{"defense":20}}},"utility":{"Spatial_Accuracy":{"max":1,"req":""},"Good_Hands":{"max":3,"req":""},"Perseverance":{"max":3,"req":""},"Haste":{"max":1,"req":""},"Awareness":{"max":4,"req":{"utility":4}},"Expanded_Mind":{"max":4,"req":{"utility":4}},"Greed":{"max":1,"req":{"utility":8}},"Meditation":{"max":3,"req":{"utility":8}},"Utility_Mastery":{"max":2,"req":{"utility":8}},"Insight":{"max":1,"req":{"utility":8}},"Quickness":{"max":3,"req":{"utility":12}},"Blink_of_an_Eye":{"max":1,"req":{"utility":12}},"Intelligence":{"max":3,"req":{"utility":16}},"Mystical_Vision":{"max":1,"req":{"utility":16}},"Presence_of_the_Master":{"max":1,"req":{"utility":20}}}}}
```

test data

```
{"json":1}
```

jsonlint.com tells me both of these data-sets are valid json so why wont it parse properly?

all the data comes from a php array thats converted via json_encode()

```
return array(
    "points"    => array( // for js
        "allowed"   => 30,
        "current"   => 0,
        "offense"   => 0,
        "defense"   => 0,
        "utility"   => 0,
    ),
    "current"   => array( // for js
        "offense"   => new stdClass,
        "defense"   => new stdClass,
        "utility"   => new stdClass,
    ),
    "trees"     => array(
        "offense"   => $offense, // the trees
        "defense"   => $defense,
        "utility"   => $utility,
    ),
);
```

been staring at it for a while and just cant see where the error would be coming from

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log()`ing `$('a.json.data', mastery).text()`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AbWPq/ - seems like no problems

Comment: yea i was doing that - it appeared to be coming out correct - ive just pasted this into jsonlint and it appears as though the error comes from the json data being duplicated (so a 2nd object follows the first directly and that causes the silent fails!)

Comment: Do you have JSON Object or String? Try `typeof`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question:

> a simple mistake being overlooked that i only picked up on when
>   checking the console.log as suggested by JamWaffles
>
> the gist of it is this; var mastery is picking up 2 divs (the parent
>   that i want and the direct child which i dont) - and as both are
>   parents to the json data.. thats where the duplication comes from
>
> silly
>
> thanks jamwaffles!